# How do I test for "prevObject"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I use this code...

```
var $row = $(this).next("tr[data-control]")
```

I sometimes get the row I need, but due to siblings, I might also get "prevObject" (in console log).

How do I test for prevObject?

I've tried this...

```
if ($row == undefined) {}
```

and this...

```
if ($row == prevObject) {}
```

and this...

```
if ($row == $(this)) {}
```

But none of those works.

How do I test if my var is prevObject?

Thanks.

Comment: Removed C# tag as it was irrelevant :)

Comment: What you're seeing in the console is just a jQuery object that has a prevObject property. There's no need to test for this ?

Comment: @adeno ... well if I do a ... $row.find("tr[data-error]") ... then sometimes I get the data-error row and sometimes I need to go to the parent to find the row ... but I need to figure out when $row.find("tr[data-error]") is returning prevObject and when it returns the row. If it returns the prevObject, then I need to do this ... $row.parent().find("tr[data-error]").

Comment: I've made a little sample ... http://jsfiddle.net/n2MgS/1 ... I need to test if I have to go to "$(this).parent().next(...". In my jsfiddle sample, I need both data-error divs to show the Error! text

Comment: Add the following inside your `.each` on your fiddle and check the console: `console.log($(this).next('div[data-error]').length ? 'EXIST' : 'DOES NOT EXIST')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, if `$row = "prevObj"` in your console, it means something is wrong in your selection and you're not getting an Element Object. It's not "because of siblings." What you appear to want to check for is "if element exist."

The easiest way to do this is to check `length`. Such as:

```
if ($row.length) {
    /* row element exist, do work */
}
else { /* $row element does NOT exist */ }
```

I answered something similar on another post and even made a plugin. Please see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery/) and [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery/13313296#13313296)

## jsFiddle

Comment: Thanks :) ... So is this the best way to do it ... http://jsfiddle.net/n2MgS/2/ ... ?

Comment: @MojoDK Kind of. Except `if ($row.length == 0)` is not necessary, as this is the same as `if (!$row.length)`, since `0` is interpreted as `false` anyway.

Comment: Another tip, try keeping your single tagged elements (like `input`) closed. Example: `<input type="text" />`. Note the slash at the end. This ensures better "readability" for both the browser and any "IDE" you might use.

Comment: always check if a jquery object exists. checking its length is the way to do this, good answer.